# How do I use a SQLiteDatabase after creating the methods?

Tags: java, android, sql, android-sqlite

I have a DBHelper class:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="DBHelper";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="tblCars";
    public static final String COLUMN_MANUFACTURER="Manufacturer";
    public static final String COLUMN_YEAR="Year";
    public static final String COLUMN_HANDNUMBER="Handnumber";
    public static final String COLUMN_CARNUMBER="Carnumber";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRICE="Price";
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("create table tblCars" + "(id integer primary key, manufacturer text, year text, handnumber text, carnumber text, price integer)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblCars");
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void insertCar(Car c)
    {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

        String query = "select * from tblCars";
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);

        cv.put(COLUMN_MANUFACTURER,c.getManufacturer());
        cv.put(COLUMN_YEAR,c.getYear());
        cv.put(COLUMN_HANDNUMBER,c.getHandnumber());
        cv.put(COLUMN_CARNUMBER, c.getCarnumber());
        cv.put(COLUMN_PRICE,c.getPrice());

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        db.close();

    }
}
```

I want to be able to allow the user to add a car so I went ahead and made an activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddCar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:text="Add Car"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="107dp"
        android:text="Number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etOwnerNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="000-000-0000"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
        android:text="Manufacturer" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etManu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Manufacturer"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="202dp"
        android:text="Year" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etYear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Year"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Hand no." />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etHandNum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="1,2, etc..."
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/etCarNum"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Car no." />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etCarNum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_marginBottom="171dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Car Number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="125dp"
        android:text="Price" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Price"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and I want to take the information about the car from that, and to put it into an object (Car), and afterwards I want to store it in the database, but I cannot use my "insertCar" method for some reason, it keeps giving me the error "Cannot resolve symbol insertCar". Happens whenever I try to use the method in any class (in this case a new class "Add")

```
 Car car=new Car(stManu,stYear,stHandNum,stCarNum);
 insertCar(car);
```

Comment: what's the reason ? why can't you use the `insertCar` method ?

Comment: And also in `insertCar` method you are not inserting the data simply selecting it.

Comment: Says "cannot resolve symbol insertCar", and how do I go on about to inserting it then?

Comment: then post it like this with error. And can you add the code which saying that. You are definitely calling it in a wrong way

Comment: Thanks, edited the post now if you're able to take a look

Comment: you are calling `insertCar` directly. I suppose `insertCar` method is defined in another file and you are trying to call `insertCar` from another file. Do it like this `new DBHelper.insertCar(car)`

Comment: And also read about objects in Java

Comment: Lemme know if this helped for you or not

Comment: Sorry, it gives me this error now: https://i.imgur.com/1GxT7Cg.png

Comment: why are you using `()` after DBHelper ? Check my answer again

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper dbHelper;
    EditText etName,etYear,etMobileNo,etManufacturer,etHandNo,etPrice,etCarNo;
    Car car;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etCarNo=findViewById(R.id.etCarNum);
    etName=findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etYear=findViewById(R.id.etYear);
    etMobileNo=findViewById(R.id.etOwnerNumber;
    etManufacturer=findViewById(R.id.etManu);
    etHandNo=findViewById(R.id.etHandNum);
    etPrice=findViewById(R.id.etPrice);

    car=new Car();
    dbHelper=new DBHelper(this);

    car.setCarNo(etCarNo.getText().toString());
    car.setName(etName.getText().toString());
    car.setYear(etYear.getText().toString());
    car.setMobileNo(etMobileNo.getText().toString());
    car.setManufacturer(etManufacturer.getText().toString());
    car.setHandNo(etHandNo.getText().toString());
    car.setPrice(etPrice.getText().toString());

    dbHelper.insertCar(car);
   }
}
```

please try it....

Comment: @Monali `dbhelper=new DBHelpter(this);` or `dbHelper=new DBHelper(this);` ?

Comment: `dbHelper.inserCar(car); ` or `dbhelper.inserCar(car);` ?

Comment: there is still one more error `new DBHelpter(this);` or `new DBHelper(this);` ? It's all typo